Pattern 'VH' did not match any bands : Sentinel 1 between 2014 and 2017
I'm trying to use Sentinel 1 images on GEE in order to compute RVI between 2014 and 2017. While I'm seeing the VH band after 2017 I don't get any between 2014 and 2017. Does anyone have an idea of the reason and how to get this band ?
Link to my code to reproduce the error : https://code.earthengine.google.com/bb72065556ffed1b35ef34eb7f627189
